# Difference between condition variable and condition predicate in java synchronization

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

I am looking for an example with explanation to understand the difference between condition variable and condition predicate in java. 
This is in the context of synchronization. 
Also I would like to know whether these terms are actual java terms found in java documentations or other authors refer to these terms?

To clarify the question further, consider this example (taken from Java Concurrency book):

```
@ThreadSafe
public class BoundedBuffer<V> extends BaseBoundedBuffer<V> {

    public BoundedBuffer(int size) { super(size); }

    // BLOCKS-UNTIL: not-full
    public  synchronized  void put(V v) throws InterruptedException {
        while (isFull())
            wait();
        doPut(v);
        notifyAll();
    }

    // BLOCKS-UNTIL: not-empty
    public  synchronized  V take() throws InterruptedException {
        while (isEmpty())
            wait();
        V v = doTake();
        notifyAll();
        return v;
    } 
}
```

What is condition variable, what is condition predicate? You may have a better and simpler example than this to explain the difference. I am confused as what exactly each one is referring to (condition variable vs predicate), whether they are the same thing or not.

Someone understanding the low level of java concurrency is probably the best to answer this question.

Comment: Surely, the last question could be answered simply by looking at the Java documentation?

Comment: "I would like to know whether these terms are actual java terms found in java documentations or other authors refer to these terms?" ***I*** would like to know why you are asking a question about these terms if you don't even know where you got them from? Where *did* you get them from? Your question is completely unanswerable without that context.

Comment: @EJP: These are terms I heard over the past few years when dealing with java concurrency. The first time I heard them in a Berkeley lecture video posted on youtube. Then later I've heard from various people and everytime it caught my attention more. I am not sure if these terms are specific to java, specific to concurrency patterns or what. Last time I heard it was in an interview question.  So I assume there must be some place where this condition concurrency pattern is explained.

Comment: The question refers to POSIX and its engineers. As a young se candidate, I can see I'm laying my foundations properly and radically. ELHAMDULILLAH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *condition variable* is a construct provided by an OS or threading system that provides *wait* and *notify* operations and that maintains a set of waiting threads.

A *condition predicate* is a predicate (a boolean-valued function or expression) called or implemented by code that uses a condition variable. Briefly, a thread waits on a condition variable until the predicate is true, and a thread notifies (or signals) the condition variable when the predicate becomes true.

Put another way, a condition predicate is code that is evaluated to test something about the logical state of the object, whereas a condition variable is a mechanism to communicate among threads that are changing the object's state and that are waiting for the object to change state.

The example code is somewhat confusing because it uses two condition predicates with the same condition variable. A thread doing a *put* tests the `isFull` predicate (it doesn't have to be a function; it could be a Boolean expression) and a thread doing a *take* tests the `isEmpty` predicate. They both use the same condition variable, which is the one associated with `this`, the buffer object. Note that the condition tested in the while-loop is the inverse of the predicate. A thread doing a *put* operation waits *until* the predicate is true, so the code waits *while* the predicate is not true.

The term *condition predicate* doesn't appear to be standardized. It's a reasonably descriptive term, and Goetz uses it in *Java Concurrency in Practice*. In Lampson and Redell, *Experience with Processes and Monitors in Mesa*, they mostly just use the term *predicate*. (Java's object monitors are almost an exact copy of Mesa's. Pthreads' are also very similar.) I've also seen the terms *precondition* or *state predicate* used.

The term *condition variable* is a fairly standard term of art for this construct. It's used by Mesa and Pthreads and probably dates back to Hoare's original work with monitors. Oddly, Java specifications don't use this term very much; they simply refer to the monitor associated with each object and that it can be locked, unlocked, awaited, or notified. There is however a `Condition` interface and implementations in the `java.util.concurrent.locks` package. The `Condition` interface represents a condition variable.

Comment: Very well said. Thank you.

Comment: Nice explanation and meaning of predicate is simply put.

Answer (score 0):

Condition variable it's a boolean that verifies one condition (can be a flag for waiting another task/thread).

Condition Predicates are lambda expressions, you can read more about it here:

http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/04/04/how-to-use-predicate-in-java-8/

Answer (score 0):

Condition variable - http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2010/09/java-concurrency-part-5-monitors-locks-and-conditions.html:
A condition variable is a kind of queue of process who are waiting on the same condition

Condition predicate - [really long link](http://books.google.com/books?id=EK43StEVfJIC&pg=PT312&lpg=PT312&dq=condition%20predicate%20concurrency%20java&source=bl&ots=uoTEA8sLgs&sig=1RLRIf8WC7u8ZYZRLgLYFA2YML0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5FHkU4fSMIT1oAS084GABQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=condition%20predicate%20concurrency%20java&f=false): 
A condition predicate is the precondition that makes an operation state dependent in the first place

My interpretation: A condition variable is a queue of processes that wait on a common condition predicate (which may or may not be wrong - again, my interpretation).